# How to disable read more link if the description is in the default size

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have just developed a new wordpress theme but there is an unfigured problem.

So, I have used jQuery to add a read more and a show less link under the description.

The only problem that I have here is that I don't want to show the link if the height is 16 pixels so I want to enable it only if the description height is bigger than 16 pixel.

Any one has any idea for this? Thankyou.

```js
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('.the_description').find('a[href="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.expand = !this.expand;
    jQuery(this).text(this.expand?"Click to collapse":"Click to read more");
    jQuery(this).closest('.the_description').find('.small, .big').toggleClass('small big');
  });
});
```

```css
.small {
  height: 16px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.big {
  height: auto;
}

.desc_more {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="the_description">
  <div class="small">
    This is a test description.
  </div>
  <div class="desc_more">
    <a href="#">Click to read more</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Will it have the class of `small`?

Comment: Hi Shiladitya, thanks for the reply and edit.So the default size is 16 pixels with one line of text and when its only one line I dont want to display the click to read more but I want to enable it only if it has more text.

Comment: Binding an event to the height of something is a terrible idea.  Someone else goes in to change the height (font-size, line-height, padding etc) and now javascript is broken.  You should consider an alternative solution.  [Decoupling Your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript](https://philipwalton.com/articles/decoupling-html-css-and-javascript/).

Comment: I renamed $ to jQuery thats the reason why didnt work for me thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/ztys5y05/

```js
$(function() {
  $('.small').each(function(){
    if($(this).find('span').height() <= 18){
      $(this).next('div.desc_more').hide();
    } else {
      $('.the_description').find('a[href="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.expand = !this.expand;
        jQuery(this).text(this.expand?"Click to collapse":"Click to read more");
        jQuery(this).closest('.the_description').find('.small, .big').toggleClass('small big');      
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.small {
  height: 16px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.big {
  height: auto;
}

.desc_more {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="the_description">
  <div class="small">
    <span>
      This is a test description.
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="desc_more">
    <a href="#">Click to read more</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="the_description">
  <div class="small">
    <span>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum    
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="desc_more">
    <a href="#">Click to read more</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: @Gazi Please have a look into the answer, this might help you.

Comment: Thanks but its not showing anymore if I add more text now its only showing one line I tested to add more lines a bigger paragraph which is bigger than 16 pixel but now it stacks at 16 pixel.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var height = $(".small").height();
  if(height < 16)
      $(".desc_more").hide();
   else
      $(".desc_more").show();  
});
```

I think you are talking about height of div with text "This is a test description." You could use above code for relevant elements

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery get the height of the element with .css('height')

You can then use show() and hide(), which show and hide the content respectively.

```
if ($('.small').css('height') > 16)
{
  $('.desc_more').show();
}
else{
  $('.desc_more').hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS max-height property to set the maximum height of div :

```
.small {
    max-height: 16px;
    }
```

Good luck

Comment: sure just did it much better thankyou.I have used also the min-height.